# Kafka 2.9.1 producer 0.8.2.1 compile vs runtime dependencies

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

So the Kakfa config properties changed for producers in api 0.8.2; After working past that and getting my java Producer to compile I get an exception. The producer is aimed at my Kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.1 cluster's nodes, and I get this exception about the `DefaultSerializer` not instanciating:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder Does it have a public no-argument constructor?
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:136)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:216)
........
```

Given this is implemented in Kakfa I wonder if compiling with Kafka as a dependency was not sufficient as maybe I needed to package in one or more Kafka jars when running. I haven't found documentation (up to date nor otherwise) about this. Is there a producer runtime jar I'm missing?

For reference I'm including my `build.gradle` here (it's a bit messy). The excludes in the compile were a new addition after already getting this error, so the error happens with or without those lines in the dependencies block. I did try only relying on the `kafka-client` module for 0.8.2 but I don't think that works for a producer. Here is the file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.0'
    }
}

group 'lamblin'
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: "com.google.protobuf"

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

// Eliminates bootstrap class warning from javac
//tasks.withType(Compile) {
//    options.bootClasspath = "$JDK6_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar"
//}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java-util', version: '3.0.0-beta-1'
    compile group: 'com.google.transit', name: 'gtfs-realtime-bindings', version: '0.0.4'
    compile group: 'com.offbytwo', name: 'docopt', version: '0.6.0.20150202'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.9.1', version: '0.8.2.1' {
    compile ('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.9.1:0.8.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
        exclude group: 'javax.jmx', module: 'jms'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
    }
}

protobuf {
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                python { }
            }
        }
    }
    protoc {
        //  artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-alpha-3'
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:2.6.1'
    }
}
// First Application Script
mainClassName = "com.insight.lamblin.GtfsToJson"
applicationName = "gtfsToJson"

// Subsequent Scripts
task createAllStartScripts() << {
    // This task is added to by a loop over the scripts array creating-sub tasks
}
def scripts = [ 'gtfsToJson': 'com.insight.lamblin.GtfsToJson',
                'rawGtfsKafkaProducer': 'com.insight.lamblin.RawGtfsKafkaProducer'
]
scripts.each() { scriptName, className ->
    def t = tasks.create(name: scriptName+'StartScript', type: CreateStartScripts) {
        mainClassName = className
        applicationName = scriptName
        outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'scripts')
        classpath = jar.outputs.files + project.configurations.runtime
    }
    applicationDistribution.into("bin") {
        from(t)
        fileMode = 0755
    }
    createAllStartScripts.dependsOn(t)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scene: In a nondescript church basement a circle of folding metal chairs is occupied by a variety of middle-aged men and a few women, most of whom have glasses and appear disinterested. There is a box of coffee and some half-doughnuts arranged on a plastic plate in turn on a chipped, uncovered, folding table by a wall adjacent to the entrance.

Daniel: Hi, my name's Daniel, and I am a... (sob)... documentation skimmer.
Group (slowly): Welcome Daniel.

That screen-play bit was written because it seems my Kafka question drew only crickets, so I'm keeping it a little interesting here... feeling lonesome.

In my defense there's 10s of seemingly authoritative kafka.apache.org documents on the property settings for producers. The `kafka.serializer.DefaultSerializer` is very prominent and common in almost all examples of setting properties, and the Java producer examples completely lack details on the properties or on running the example code.

Also, despite the name, "default", there is no default value for this property, thus the requirement to set it. That seems like a silly detail, but it must have made sense to some one at the Kafka development team.

When running a Kafka producer written in Java, the producer should set encoders from the few Java specific encoders available. The aforementioned one seems to be Scala specific. For Java you're interested in [`org.apache.kafka.common.serialization`](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-summary.html) and you the equivalent to the default serializer is: [`ByteArraySerializer`](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer.html). If you set `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` it should work. The better way to set those is using the static strings in [`ProducerConfig`](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.html) like `ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG`.

Setup is a bit like:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer; 
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig; 
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord; 
... 
import java.util.Properties;
...
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
          "172.31.22.7:9092,172.31.22.6:9092,172.31.22.5:9092,172.31.22.4:9092"); 
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"); 
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"); 
KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props); 
...
```

Comment: sometimes.. I just read the 'Quick start' section... I know it's wrong... ;-)